# Convert dynamic XML file to pandas Dataframe

Tags: xml, pandas, dataframe, xml-parsing

thanks for your time et your attention. This is the first time I posted in stackoverflow so excuse me if I'm clumsy.

Essentially I'm coding in Python, but it is the first time I'm parsing a XML File. I've been working on it for a few weeks, but I'm blocked on one point or more.

My sample is :

```
<record date="2023-09-14" time="12:00:00" id="ALARM:UniqueID1">
  <field name="fruit">apple</field>
  <field name="color">red</field>
  <field name="animal">cat</field>
</record>
<record date="2023-09-15" time="14:00:00" id="ALARM:UniqueID2">
  <field name="fruit">banana</field>
  <field name="color">yellow</field>
  <field name="animal">dog</field>
</record>
```

The number of records are dynamic and the name of the balise field can change for each record. Here, my code ton parse this xml file to pandas dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et
import re
import itertools

with open('DataFile.xml') as f:
    chain_element = itertools.chain('<main>', f, '</main>')
    main_root = et.fromstringlist(chain_element)

    col_names = ["col1", "col2", "col3", "itemA", "itemB", 'itemC']
    data_entries = []

    listA = []
    listB = []
    listC = []

    for element in main_root.findall('element'):
      
      Data1 = element.get('col1')
      Data2 = element.get('col2')
      Data3 = element.get('col3')

      itemA = element.getchildren()[0].text
      itemB = element.getchildren()[1].text
      itemC = element.getchildren()[2].text

      data_entries.append({"col1": Data1, "col2": Data2, "col3": Data3, "itemA" : itemA,
                  "itemB" : itemB,  "itemC" : itemC})

    result_df = pd.DataFrame(data_entries, columns = col_names)
    print(result_df)
```

But for each record I can have different field missing or not, in this case I would like a "None" in the dataframe. But I don't find a solution at the moment.

Again, thanks for you time et for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was a very interesting question - thanks for that!
What you want to do can be done with lxml and xpath. I'll try to explain as we go along:

```
from lxml import etree
import pandas as pd
records = """[your xml above]"""

root = etree.fromstring(records)
num_recs = int(root.xpath('count(//record)')) #count the number of records; 2, in this case
rec_grid = [[] for __ in range(num_recs)] #intitalize a list of sublists (2 in this case, with each sublist holding the relevant fields
fields = ["date","time","id","system_inst", "system_name", "flags", "alias", "group", "priority", "text", "trtext", "end", "duration", "ackts", "user", "acktext", "ivtext"]

paths = root.xpath('//record') #this contains a list of the 2 locations of the records
counter = 0
for path in paths:    
    for fld in fields[:3]: #the first 3 fields are in a different sub-location than the other 14             
        target = f'(./@{fld})' #using f-strings to populate the full path
        if path.xpath(target):
                rec_grid[counter].append(path.xpath(target)[0]) #we start populating our current sublist with the relevant info            
        else:
                rec_grid[counter].append('NA')

    for fld in fields[3:]:  # and now for the rest of the fields            
        target = f'(./field[@name="{fld}"]/text())'
        if path.xpath(target):
            rec_grid[counter].append(path.xpath(target)[0]) 
        else:
            rec_grid[counter].append('NA')
    counter+=1

df = pd.DataFrame(rec_grid, columns=fields) #now that we have our lists, create a df
df
```

Output is too long to reproduce here, but it looks like the linked image in your question.

You could simplify it (a bit) by using a helper function like so:

```
def proc_target(path,target,counter):
    if path.xpath(target):
        rec_grid[counter].append(path.xpath(target)[0])               
    else:
        rec_grid[counter].append('NA')
```

and change the `for` loop to:

```
for path in paths:    
    for fld in fields[:3]:              
        target = f'(./@{fld})'
        proc_target(path,target,counter)
    for fld in fields[3:]:              
        target = f'(./field[@name="{fld}"]/text())'
        proc_target(path,target,counter)        
    counter+=1
```

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if this would work.

First

```
pip install pandas_read_xml
```

Then

```
import pandas_read_xml as pdx

df = pdx.read_xml('Alarm.xml')
```

You may need to

```
df = pdx.flatten(df)
```